# Why doesn't this proof of Brouwer's Invariance of Domain theorem work?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I've heard that Brouwer's invariance of domain problem is very difficult to prove. This confuses me, though, since it seems like a proof along the following lines should work:

Consider the sphere $S^m$ embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$ via a mapping $\phi$ (which is a homeomorphism onto the image), where $m>n-1$. Show that $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \phi(S^m)$ is still connected (maybe this is harder than I'm giving it credit for). Then it is easy to see that $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are not homeomorphic for $n>m$ from the simple fact that $S^{m-1}$ disconnects $\mathbb{R}^m$ but any homeomorphic embedding of it does not disconnect $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Where does this go wrong?

Comment: Brouwers invariance of domain theorem states more than just that $\Bbb{R}^n$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}^m$. Also I think that indeed you are not giving enough credit to the difficulty of the connectedness claim.

Comment: The rest of the statement of Brouwer’s invariance of domain theorem follows from some relatively elementary simple arguments though, doesn’t it?

Comment: Every way that I know of to prove that connectedness claim is significantly harder than the easiest proofs that $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Ah so it is indeed the part I’m not giving enough credit to.

Answer (score 0):

The lowest dimensional case $n=1,m=2$ already fails: $\Bbb R^m\setminus f[S^1]$ is *disconnected* (although this is hard to show, look up Jordan's curve theorem), not connected. The sphere disconnection fact is in fact very hard, and you underestimate that hardness IMO.

Comment: We don’t need the Jordan curve theorem since it is enough to show that the regular embedding of $S^1$ into $\mathbb{R}^2$ disconnects it. It then remains to show that any embedding of $S^1$ into higher dimensional space does not disconnect it.

Comment: @exfret that’s exactly what the Jordan curve theorem says. What is a regular embedding anyway?

Comment: I mean, just the set $\{(x,y)\vert x^2+y^2=1\}$

Comment: Also, I don’t see how your example is a counterexample. 2 is not less than or equal to 1. (I mixed up $n$’s and $m$’s so maybe this is the source of confusion).

Comment: You want the version where we have ahomeomorphic copy of $S^1$, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: @exfret you said $n \le m$ so that's what I respond to.

Comment: Why won’t it work? We show that the unit circle disconnects it, and any homeomorphic embedding into higher dimensional space does not disconnect it. These are opposite statements.

Comment: Also you’re right, I’ll fix that typo.